# what's the difference between savedInstanceState and outState in onSaveInstanceState() event?

Tags: java, android

So what is the difference between them? I searched for about half an hour and still got no clue! In the onSaveInstanceState() event, I saw somebody used outState, and some used savedInstanceState, and when ever I type Ctrl + Space in Eclipse, it only shows me the "Bundle outState" as a parameter.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle onState){...};

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bunble savedInstanceState){...};

//what is the difference between them?
```

P/S: Sorry for this "nooby" question but I'm a beginner and trying to figure it out myself so...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Its just a variable name, you can use however you want,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual difference between them. The Bundle is passed to the method as a parameter and this is the name your are assigning it so you can reference it inside the method.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle onState){
    onState.getInt.....

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bunble savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.getInt...

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bunble whatEverYouLike){
    whatEverYouLike.getInt...
```

They are all the same.